# Getting bearer or AuthResult from client?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am instantiating graph like this:

```
public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantName)
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await
       GetAuthenticationResult(tenantName, clientId, clientSecret);

    var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers
                .Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }));

    return client;
}
```

I have another extension method where I need the Bearer from the client:

```
public static async Task<T> GetRESTResult<T>(this GraphServiceClient client, string url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", HERE????.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);
    var jsonStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr.Result);
}
```

How do you get the authresult/bearer from a given client object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pulling the token *from* the SDK, you should [send the HTTP requests through the SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library):

```
public static async Task<T> GetRESTResult<T>(this GraphServiceClient client, string url)
{
    // Create the request message and add the content.
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

    // Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
    await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);

    // Send the request and get the response.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

    // Process the response
    var jsonStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr.Result);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!